# Firestore query document based on comparison of 2 fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Say I have this document

```
userProfile: {
  createdAt: '2018-01-01',
  updatedAt: '2018-01-04'
}
```

I want to retrieve all `userProfiles` that were updated after their creation, that means those that satisfy `createdAt < updatedAt`. 
Can you do that in Firestore?

Something like this, but where the second operand is a field, not a value:

```
userProfileRef.where("createdAt", "<", "updatedAt")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do that with "standard" Firestore queries.

The easiest way would be to either:

1. Have a default "dummy" date (e.g. 1900-01-01) in the `updatedAt` field if the doc was never updated after creation. You would then query with `userProfileRef.where("updatedAt", ">", "1900-01-01")`

or

2. Have a specific flag in the document that you would update when you change the value of the `updatedAt` field (i.e. when you update the doc after creation).

   ---

Note that you cannot query for documents that don't contain a given field (watch this official [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI) for more details), therefore you cannot rely on the absence of the `updatedAt` field.